# R: C stack error when using recursive function - optimizing the code

Tags: r, recursion, stack

I am trying to make a simple "model" of loss of an initial value based on a number of criteria, as seen in my code below:

```
mtDNAlen = 16299
copies = 10
mito = 50
fraction = copies*mtDNAlen*0.75
Rounds = 40


A = data.frame(
  Length = c(rep(mtDNAlen,copies))
)
data = list()

for (i in 1:mito){
  data[[i]]=list()
}

for (i in 1:length(data)){
  for (j in 1:(Rounds+1)){
    data[[i]][[j]]=data.frame(A)
}}

finaldata = data.frame(X = seq(1,copies,1))

random.sample = function(x) {
  x = sample(sample.data, copies, 
             prob=Prob, 
             replace=FALSE)
  if (sum(x) > fraction) return(x)
  Recall(x)
}

for (i in 1:length(data)){
  for(j in 1:Rounds){
    data[[i]][[j]]$Deletion = sample(c("Yes","No"), nrow(data[[i]][[j]]), prob=c(0.05,0.95), replace=TRUE)
    data[[i]][[j]]$DelLength = ifelse(data[[i]][[j]]$Deletion == "Yes", sample(seq(0,15000,1), replace = TRUE),0)
    data[[i]][[j]]$Length = data[[i]][[j]]$Length - data[[i]][[j]]$DelLength
    data[[i]][[j]] = data[[i]][[j]][data[[i]][[j]]$Length > 2000,]
    data[[i]][[j]] = rbind(data[[i]][[j]],data[[i]][[j]])

    Prob = c(rep(16300,nrow(data[[i]][[j]]))) - data[[i]][[j]]$Length
    Prob = Prob / sum(Prob)

    sample.data = c(data[[i]][[j]]$Length)
    data[[i]][[j+1]]$Length = random.sample(sample.data)

    finaldata[[i]] = data[[i]][[j+1]]$Length
  }
}
```

However, when I try to run my code I get the following error:

```
Error: C stack usage  7969700 is too close to the limit
```

After searching, this seems to occur when using recursive functions. However, I am new to these types of functions, and I don't know how to optimise my code further, in order to et rig of this error.

I should mention, that when I run my code without `prob=Prob` in the `random.sample` function, there is no error. So I guess the error comes from having to redo the `random.sample` so many times? Can I do this in a better way to avoid the C stack error? I haven't been able to find an alternative myself.
Finally, if I set `Rounds` and `mito` to very small values, I can complete the calculation, but it is not really usable for me...

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried to switch to using `repeat` instead, making my `for loop` look like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(data)){
  for(j in 1:Rounds){
    data[[i]][[j]]$Deletion = sample(c("Yes","No"), nrow(data[[i]][[j]]), prob=c(0.05,0.95), replace=TRUE)
    data[[i]][[j]]$DelLength = ifelse(data[[i]][[j]]$Deletion == "Yes", sample(seq(0,15000,1), replace = TRUE),0)
    data[[i]][[j]]$Length = data[[i]][[j]]$Length - data[[i]][[j]]$DelLength
    data[[i]][[j]] = data[[i]][[j]][data[[i]][[j]]$Length > 2000,]
    data[[i]][[j]] = rbind(data[[i]][[j]],data[[i]][[j]])

    Prob = c(rep(16300,nrow(data[[i]][[j]]))) - data[[i]][[j]]$Length
    Prob = Prob / sum(Prob)

    sample.data = c(data[[i]][[j]]$Length)

    repeat {
      v2 <- sample(sample.data, copies, 
                   prob=Prob, 
                   replace=FALSE)
      if( sum(v2) > fraction ) 
        break
    } 
    return(v2)

    data[[i]][[j+1]]$Length = v2

    finaldata[[i]] = data[[i]][[j+1]]$Length
  }
}
```

However, now I can't get the sampled data to go to the next dataframe, ie. the line `data[[i]][[j+1]]$Length = v2` seems to not be working. I can see v2 is getting generated and it looks to have the appropriate form and data stored...

Comment: I dont think the `c` tag is appropriate here. I can barely read the above code.

Comment: I dont know R, but just find place where function call herself and check is it finite. You should also rewrite recursion to iteration form, using example while.
Recursion is stack killer because variable from prev call functions are in stack until end of recursion.

Comment: @Yastanub I'm really sorry about that!

Comment: @IgorGalczak I tried updating my code based on your input, thanks! However, I'm still having some problems and am honestly a bit stuck on this...